# What is the plural of "API"?

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the plural of "API" ([Application programming interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface))

Is it part of English irregular plurals ending in "-i"?

Comment: Without any more context, I'd say add an "s." APIs.

Comment: If you're talking about Application Programming Interfaces, the well-established plural is "APIs".

Answer (score 8):

**APIs**

API could mean a lot of things. The list can be easily found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_%28disambiguation%29.

But as it is in most cases an acronym, when you append *s* to it, it unambiguously indicates plurality of whatever the acronym stands for.

As in Computer science - *API* stands for *Application Programming Interface*. The plural of which is *Application Programming Interfaces* so the acronym in plural is *APIs*